# Location and markers not loading on android map fragment the second time

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-markers

I have an activity with 5 tabs, each of which contains a fragment.
The middle tab contains a layout in which I'm dynamically adding a map fragment. Everything works smooth till here.
Now, when I move to tab 1 or 5 and come back to this 3rd tab, all my markers and current location vanish from the map!

I have tried to find the problem using logs, and every method including onMapReady() (I am adding the markers and enabling the current location inside this function) is being called, but nothing shows up on the map. It takes time to process the marker data and prints the logs. But nothing shows up. So it is all the more puzzling!

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Hard to debug code that we can't see.

Comment: post the code for what you did when switching between tabs and also your mapfragment code. SO we can understand where is the issue.

Comment: you views may destroyed, share your code first

Answer (score 0):

You can always make use of Shared Preference when you want to store small amount of data locally, which you don't want to loose even when user switch in between apps. You case looks similar because the markers vanish when you switch in between tabs on your activity. For current location you can always call onLocationChanged whenever your map is instantiated.

For storing map markers in shared preference... Here is a small code snippet.. This code saves the state of markers when back button is pressed.. you can pass the same method (SavePreferences()) in the listener when you change tabs and retrieve it when the tabs for map loads.

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    private List<Marker> markerList;

    public MapsActivity(){
        if(markerList == null){
            markerList = new ArrayList<Marker>();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        LoadPreferences();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
        String label = data.getString("sum");
        int newLatitude = data.getInt("firstNumber");
        int newLongitude = data.getInt("secondNumber");

        MarkerOptions mo = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(newLatitude, newLongitude)).title(label);
        markerList.add(mMap.addMarker(mo));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        super.onBackPressed();
        SavePreferences();
    }

    private void SavePreferences(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putInt("listSize", markerList.size());

        for(int i = 0; i <markerList.size(); i++){
            editor.putFloat("lat"+i, (float) markerList.get(i).getPosition().latitude);
            editor.putFloat("long"+i, (float) markerList.get(i).getPosition().longitude);
            editor.putString("title"+i, markerList.get(i).getTitle());
        }

        editor.commit(); 
    }

    private void LoadPreferences(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

        int size = sharedPreferences.getInt("listSize", 0);
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            double lat = (double) sharedPreferences.getFloat("lat"+i,0);
            double longit = (double) sharedPreferences.getFloat("long"+i,0);
            String title = sharedPreferences.getString("title"+i,"NULL");

            markerList.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, longit)).title(title)));
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this would Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Long time since you wrote this but I stumbled upon your question today when I was searching for a solution. Short after I was able to solve it for me by, before disconnecting the `GoogleApiClient`, also remove the `ConnectionCallbackListener` (my `Activity`), like:

```
googleApiClient.unregisterConnectionCallbacks(this);
googleApiClient.disconnect();
```

My flow is like this:
Initialize `MapView` when creating view. Connect the `GoogleApiClient`. On `ConnectionCallbackListener.onConnected()` I do the things I need, and then unregistering and disconnecting.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon a similar problem, though it involved ending the app with the back button - not killing it. When I opened the app again after that, the markers would not show and  `googleMap.animateCamera` would throw an exception saying that `Map size cannot be 0`.

Turned out, I was using an instance of the `Fragment` and calling it from `MainActivity` via `MapFragment.getInstance( this )`, so the solution was to set `instance = null` on the fragment's `onDestroy()` method.